# keypress keyup ni keydown de Jquery no responden en smarthphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, programación-móvil

Tengo una validación de campo en mi sitio web que en cualquier navegador de pc funciona excepto en los teléfonos móviles (en ningún navegador) permitiendo la entrada de cualquier caracter; he probado de las siguientes formas:

```
 $(".onlytext").keydown(function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    return ((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122) || (key >= 193 && key <= 211) || (key >= 225 && key <= 244) || key == 218 || key == 250 || key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 32) ;

  });



 $(".onlytext").on('keypress',function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    return ((key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122) || (key >= 193 && key <= 211) || (key >= 225 && key <= 244) || key == 218 || key == 250 || key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 32) ;

  });
```

Lo anterior como dije lo he probado de las 2 formas anteriormente descritas con keyup, keydown y keypress y no funciona.

De antemano agradecido por la información que puedan brindarme.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo? Android o es un dispositivo Apple?

Comment: Si, solo ocurre con dispositivos Android, con Apple funciona bien la validación.

Comment: @U.Angel Aquí tienes dos preguntas que se asemejan en SO ingles [Pregunta numero uno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462995/jquery-keydown-keypress-keyup-enterkey-detection) [Pregunta numero dos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery?rq=1) suerte Saludos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si. Los eventos de teclado no funcionan correctamente en dispositivos móviles, no estoy seguro si en todos, pero no funcionan en Chrome de Android.

Los eventos `keyup` y `keydown` se disparan tal y como esperamos, pero el objeto `event` del callback proporciona valores incorrectos cuando intentamos acceder a las propiedades `key`, `keyCode`, `charCode`, entre otras. Por ejemplo, en algunas versiones de Chrome en Android todas las teclas arrojan el valor 229 cuando se intenta acceder a la propiedad `keyCode`, excepto la tecla de retroceso la cual arroja un 8, otras arrojan 0, etc.

Por otro lado el evento `keypress` ni siquiera es disparado o no se reconoce.

Según entiendo, esto es debido a que los teclados virtuales de los dispositivos móviles no son capaces de generar un identificador de tecla para la tecla que ha sido pulsada, caso contrario a los teclados físicos. El teclado estándar que proporciona Google no tiene forma de generar estos códigos.
Además, si esto fuese posible, sería muy difícil controlar que todos los IME de los dispositivos móviles se adaptasen a dicho comportamiento.

El equipo de desarrolladores del teclado de Android simplemente recomiendan esto: "Adaptense a ello".

La discusión es bastante larga sobre el tema. [Aquí](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639) puedes encontrar más información.

Comment: Cabe destacar que si hay teclados capaces de generar `keyCode` s pero esta condicionado a la decisión de si el usuario usa o no ese teclado en especifico, lo cual es difícil de identificar.

Comment: Muy agradecido por tu respuesta @MarioAguilarBusamante , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('textInput', function(e) {
            const char = e.data; 

                const keyCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
                if (keyCode === 43 || keyCode == 44 || keyCode === 45 || keyCode == 46) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }

            return true;
        });

    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Por favor intenta **keyup** + **keypress**

```
$(".onlytext").on('keyup keypress',function(e) {

});
```

http://www.developertut.com/jquery/jquery-keyboard-events

Comment: Los eventos se disparan, pero las teclas no son enviadas como parámetro.

Comment: Lamentablemente tampoco funciona, el tema es que con Android, el key code enviado es totalmente diferente, ninguno coincide, por ende no toma las validaciones, con Apple si lo hace bien, no he podido comprobrarlo con windows.